# Why CSS crashes in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, opencart

Got an issue with my Opencart site and safari browser (latest versions on desktop/mobile) 
some of css crashes when it's launches on safari (logo disappears, logo made by background-image then some fonts styles disables, and buttons), but works great on the other browsers.

I just don't know what to do, cause I'm a beginner

here is the site [hicandy.ru](http://hicandy.ru)

Here Safari[image: Safari]
Here Chrome[image: Chrome]

Comment: Seems ok on safari, checked right now, are you sure?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly try to resize it

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce the error but failed. Checked on both Safari and Chrome. I can only give you some general advice.

1. If you have been developing it using Safari as a main browser try to clean the cache and test your site again.
2. Check console log and network stack if all the resources have been downloaded correctly. (There may be issues with CORS for example)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website and it has some transitions particularly on sliders. Maybe this info will partially help you fix your issue:

"I noticed that some people had similar issues with Safari crashing when using the css transition property, and sure enough it was choking on the transition-property: all value applied to a global anchor selector, in conjunction with the percentage based layout (for responsive design) of the site.

When I changed the value of all to color, the site stopped crashing in Safari."

HEre is my info source in case you would like to read more: http://joelglovier.com/writing/solution-for-css-transitions-crashing-safari